# No animation when importing 3ds keyframe model

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, keyframe

Hi I have a 3DS model that has keyframe animation (a plane that lowers its wheels and puts them back up again). When I drag the file into Unity (4.3) the Animations Tab in the inspector says "No Animation data available". The Rig type is Generic. The Model gets an Animator Property. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I figured it out in the end as I don't have 3DSMax just a .3ds file I couldn't convert to fbx that way. I needed to convert the 3DS to FBX using autodesk converter (free, I used version 10.2 as the latest didn't work).

http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=14943111